# Assign ordinal numbers to list

Tags: bash

I have a file with lines like this:

```
   8 GeodeticCorrosiveness-4096     
   8 MetricalDrosky-4096            
   8 UncontrovertiblePhoebus-4096   
   9 FlabbyAutochthones-4096        
   9 UndispensedCreeds-4096         
   9 WaltonianAtomicities-4096      
  10 AtheismDuumvirate-4096         
  10 HeliocentricAllative-4096      
  10 HepaticPhaedra-4096            
  11 High-speedBuchan-4096
```

And I'd like to produce something like this:

```
8   8 GeodeticCorrosiveness-4096     
8   8 MetricalDrosky-4096            
8   8 UncontrovertiblePhoebus-4096   
5   9 FlabbyAutochthones-4096        
5   9 UndispensedCreeds-4096         
5   9 WaltonianAtomicities-4096      
2  10 AtheismDuumvirate-4096         
2  10 HeliocentricAllative-4096      
2  10 HepaticPhaedra-4096            
1  11 High-speedBuchan-4096
```

That is, the ordinal classification for each line, when sorted in descending order by the first column. Is there anything in unix that would help a shell script to do so?

Comment: Two downvotes, no comments. What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like something a short awk script and `sort` can do:

```
$ sort -srn file.txt | awk '{if ($1 != prev) num=NR; print num, $0; prev=$1}' | sort -srn
8    8 GeodeticCorrosiveness-4096     
8    8 MetricalDrosky-4096            
8    8 UncontrovertiblePhoebus-4096   
5    9 FlabbyAutochthones-4096        
5    9 UndispensedCreeds-4096         
5    9 WaltonianAtomicities-4096      
2   10 AtheismDuumvirate-4096         
2   10 HeliocentricAllative-4096      
2   10 HepaticPhaedra-4096            
1   11 High-speedBuchan-4096
```

The two calls of `sort` sort the list first, and reverse it in the end, while the awk script simply looks at the first field to figure out if it's changed, and prints the last line number where a new value was seen.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are using stable sort. I might also replace the second sort with a simple `tac`.  I love the solution, though, even more so given how quickly it was provided.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, to keep the relative order of the lines with the same number, as in the output you showed. Without it, the output is `8 Uncontrovertible`, `8 Metrical`, `8 Geodetic` etc. instead. If it matters, that I don't know, but `-s` solved it nicely.